# Question about proof of the existence of square roots

Tags: real-analysis

I'm self-studying from the book [Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950605) and I'm stuck on Theorem 1.4.5 on page 21. The aim of this theorem is to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ exists.

He starts by considering the set:
$$
T = \{ t \in \mathbb{R} \mid t^2 < 2 \}
$$
and set $\alpha = \mathrm{sup} \; T$. He then assumes that $\alpha^2 <2$ and writes:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\left( \alpha + \frac{1}{n} \right)^2 & = \alpha^2 + \frac{2 \alpha}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \\&
< \alpha^2 + \frac{2 \alpha}{n} + \frac{1}{n}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
He hasn't defined what $n$ is so I'm quite confused what the inequality exactly means. But normally, using his notation, $n \in \mathbb{N}$; if this is correct, then shouldn't the inequality sign actually be $\leq$ for the situation that $n=1$?

Comment: $n$ is indeed a natural number. You're right about the inequality sign. I think his next step will be to increase $n$ to infinity, so then you can safely assume that $n > 1$.

Comment: @StevenVanGeluwe yeah, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n$ is any (arbitrarily large) number and thus $\frac 1 n$ is an arbitrarily small one.

Comment: It's true that at $n=1$ we have an equality, but the author doesn't care, because $n$ is intended to be large.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, so he basically choose $n$ such that the inequality $<$ is valid?

Comment: Yes. Most authors don't do the difference between $<$ and $\leq$ in real analysis because we always pick $n$ to be as large as we want, and thus always greater than $1$.

Comment: @iHubble thanks for letting me know, that is useful information.